# Assembly how to count number of chars in a file and print it to the terminal

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to write a small program in assembly that receives a file name and prints out the file content to the terminal or prints the number of chars in that file if "-c" flag is given. the print of the file content working great, **but the char count is not working - it does not print anything** and I can't figure out why.

The code:

```
section .bss 
    array: resb 16 ; reserve byte - size 16
    buffer: resb 256;

section .data
    buffer_size: dw 256 

section .text
    global _start
    global read
    global write
    global open
    global close
    global strlen
    global utoa
    global read_file
    global print
    global read_file_with_flag
    global count_chars
    global open_with_flag
    global count

_start:
    pop  eax ;argc
    pop  eax ;argv[0]
    pop  eax ;argv[1]
    cmp eax ,'-c'
    je open_with_flag  
    push eax
    call open 

read_file:
    push buffer_size
    push buffer
    push eax
    call read
    cmp eax,0
    jg print
    call close
exit:
    mov ebx,eax
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80

print:
    push buffer_size
    push buffer
    push 1 ; flag descriptor of stdout
    call write
    call read_file

read:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    sub esp,4
    pushad
    mov eax, 3 ;  file descriptor 3 = read 
    ; EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI, EDI, and EBP. These registers take the consecutive arguments
    mov ebx, [ebp+8] ; file descriptor
    mov ecx, [ebp+12] ; buffer
    mov edx, [ebp+16] ; size
    int 0x80 ; transfer control to operating system 
    mov [ebp-4],eax ; save the result of the system call
    popad
    mov eax,[ebp-4] ; place returne value to eax so caller can use it 
    add esp,4       
    pop ebp
    ret ; eax hold how much was it read




write:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    sub esp,4
    pushad
    mov eax, 4 ;  file descriptor 4 = write 
    ; EBX, ECX, EDX, ESI, EDI, and EBP. These registers take the consecutive arguments
    mov ebx, [ebp+8] ; file descriptor
    mov ecx, [ebp+12] ; buffer
    mov edx, [ebp+16] ; size
    int 0x80 ; transfer control to operating system 
    mov [ebp-4],eax ; save the result of the system call
    popad
    mov eax,[ebp-4] ; place returne value to eax so caller can use it 
    add esp,4       
    pop ebp
    ret



open:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    sub esp,4 ; save 4 bits 
    pushad
    mov ebx, [ebp+8] ; move the file name into ebx
    mov ecx,[ebp+12] ; flags
    mov eax, 5 ; file descriptor 5 = open 
    int 0x80 ; transfer control to operating system 
    mov [ebp-4],eax ; save the result of the system call
    popad
    mov eax,[ebp-4] ; place returne value to eax so caller can use it 
    add esp,4 
    pop ebp
    ret

close:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    sub esp,4 ; save 4 bits 
    pushad
    mov ebx, [ebp+8]  ; move the file name into ebx
    mov eax, 6  ; file descriptor 5 = close 
    int 0x80 ; transfer control to operating system 
    mov [ebp-4],eax ; save the result of the system call
    popad
    mov eax,[ebp-4] ; place retunr value to eax so caller can use it 
    add esp,4          
    pop ebp
    ret

strlen:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    ;push ebx
    mov eax,-1

.L2:
    add eax, 1
    mov ebx, eax
    add ebx, [ebp+8]
    movzx ebx, BYTE [ebx]
    test bl,bl ; bl is the name of the low 8 bits (bits 7-0) in the ebx register
    jne .L2
    ;pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret

; convert unsigned int to string
utoa:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    pushad ; push EAX, ECX, EDX, EBX, EBP, ESP (original value), EBP, ESI, and EDI
    mov ebx, 0 ; put 0 to ebx
    mov eax, [ebp+8] ; hold pointer to i 
    mov ebx, 10  ; divider 
    mov ecx, 0 ;counter num of divs

int_to_char:
    mov edx, 0 ; put 0 to edx to "clean" it        
    div ebx     ; div eax at 10(ebx), put the remain in edx
    add edx,'0' ; add 48 to the ASCII value - convert int to string
    push edx ;push the digit to the stack
    inc ecx  ; counter++
    test eax,eax ;check if end of num eax, if eax==0 - end of string
    jne int_to_char ; continu to next digit
    mov ebx,0 ;initial ebx
    mov edx,0   ;initial edx
chars_to_array:
    add ebx,array ; ebx point to the curr byte of the array 
    pop eax ;take first num from stack
    inc edx ; counter
    mov [ebx],eax ; copy the current char into the right place in the arrray  
    mov ebx,edx ; move the counter to ebx
    loop chars_to_array ; equals to dec ecs & JNZ l1 
    popad
    mov eax,array
    pop ebp
    ret

open_with_flag:
    pop  eax ; argv[2] - the file name 
    push eax ; put the -c flag to the button of the stack 
    call open
    mov ebx,0 ; clear ebx
    mov ecx,0 ; clear ecx
    mov edx,-1 ; reset edx to -1 

read_file_with_flag:
    push buffer_size
    push buffer
    push eax ; passing the File descriptor - 0 - no file, 1 - ok -1 - error open file
    call read
    cmp eax,0 ; check if read something
    jg count_chars
    push eax ; the num of chars in the file
    call utoa
    push 4 ; file descriptor 4 = write
    push array
    push 1 ; stdout
    call write
    call close
    mov ebx,eax
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80

count_chars:
    add edx,1 ; index of the buffer 
    mov ebx,edx ; ebx stores the address of the currnet buffer index 
    add ebx,buffer ; move to the next buffer address (buffer++) 
    movzx ebx , BYTE[ebx] ; copy 1 char from the buffer to ebx
    dec eax ; eax hold how much left to read, eax--
    jmp count
    test eax, eax
    je read_file_with_flag

count:
    add ecx,1
    push ecx
    jmp count_chars
```

Comment: When counting chars what happens? No output? Crash? Wrong count?

Comment: @user176692 no output, it prints an empty line.

Comment: After `jmp count` you have two instructions that never will be reached. Why are those there?

Comment: @Michael it is my way to check if there is still something left to count, but I think you right it will be overwritten by the count function. so maybe I need to move this value to a different register before the jmp count line?

Comment: My point was that `jmp` is unconditional. So the two instruction between `jmp count` and `count:` will never be reached. They are dead code. So why are they there?

Comment: @Michael you right, it is a mistake. but I also tried to not use the count function at all and count it inside the count_chars, something like:
'
count_chars:
 add edx,1 ; index of the buffer 
 mov ebx,edx ; ebx stores the address of the currnet buffer index 
 add ebx,buffer ; move to the next buffer address (buffer++) 
 movzx ebx , BYTE[ebx] ; copy 1 char from the buffer to ebx
 dec eax ; eax hold how much left to read, eax--
 add ecx,1
 ;jmp count
 test eax, eax ; check if eax is zero
 mov eax, ecx
 je read_file_with_flag 
'

Comment: `count_chars:
 add edx,1 ; index of the buffer 
 mov ebx,edx ; ebx stores the address of the currnet buffer index 
 add ebx,buffer ; move to the next buffer address (buffer++) 
 movzx ebx , BYTE[ebx] ; copy 1 char from the buffer to ebx
 dec eax ; eax hold how much left to read, eax--
 add ecx,1
 ;jmp count
 test eax, eax ; check if eax is zero
 mov eax, ecx
 je read_file_with_flag`

Comment: If it only has to work for a "regular" file (not a pipe or whatever), just `stat` it and print the size.  Or read it and use `read`'s return value (the number of bytes read).  No need to actually loop through the data, and definitely not to `push ecx` after every byte!! That will overflow the stack if your input file is 2MiB or larger (assuming Linux's normal default user-space stack size of 8MiB).

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you but I write it for educational purposes only, the files are less than 2Mib and I want to loop through the data with a small buffer let's say with a size of 256 bytes, my goal here is to learn how to correctly work with the registers. is there any other way I can save the char counter that is more efficient instead of `ecx`?  because now it is not even working.